.Net MAUI httpclient android windows authentication
I have a maui app. There the HttpClient is working well with Windows credentials, when I am compiling for Windows apps. On Android I get a NOK on getAsync request with the Message unauthorized. How can I reach REST API on IIS server with Maui on Android?

After the information on the button the authorization is failing again. I got the 401 error and an information that the authorization is failed for the account.

Check missing permissions on your AndroidManifest.xml
Right Click on it >> open with (XML Text Editor)
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
          xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

  <application android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"> </application>

  
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
  <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.gms.permission.AD_ID" tools:node="remove" />

</manifest>

